# Best Way combine Spring Repository amd NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for one Entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, dao

I use Spring Data Repository

```
@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends CrudRepository<Some, Long> {

}
```

And I have some jdbs methods for `Some` entity. Big select with joins and etc. I implement it by `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`

And I have 2 point for get data from DB:

1. `SomeRepository`
2. `SomeDAO`(with native query, big selects)

How can I combine it?

I have 2 ways:

1. `SomeService` inject `SomeRepository` and `SomeDAO`
2. `SomeDAO` inject `SomeRepository` and have own methods and wrapp SomeRepository methods for CRUD

Comment: For example I have very hard and big native query

Comment: I know this annotation and use it. my question is not on this. There are tasks that do not solve this way. And also I will need to use the special language of the database language

Comment: Why not create a custom repository extension ? See : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations (I recently did this for an elasticsearch repository, but the same apply whatever the data store : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790434/how-to-query-elastic-with-spring-data-elastic/39793107#39793107)